# Write new lines to output

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I have been trying to create an output file that writes multiple execute scripts taking a certain parameter from an array list. So far I am getting jumbled duplicated output. How can I get one execute command on each line? Here's what I have.

```
$myArray = @(1,2,3)

foreach ($element in $myArray) {

$myobj  = "EXECUTE [masterdb].[dbo].[update_rows] @row_num=" +"'"+$element+"'"+","+ "@status = 'Fail'"
$myprocedure +=  $myobj
$myobj = $null
}
Out-file -filepath $path -inputobject $myprocedure -width 50 -force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$myprocedure` is never initialized as an array, so it becomes a string that you simply add more text to. Either you need to add a linebreak at end of the execute lines:

```
$myobj  = "EXECUTE [masterdb].[dbo].[update_rows] @row_num=" +"'"+$element+"'"+","+ "@status = 'Fail'"  + [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Or create an empty array called `$myprocedure` first:

```
$myArray = @(1,2,3)

$myprocedure = @()
$path = "test.txt"

foreach ($element in $myArray) {

    $myobj  = "EXECUTE [masterdb].[dbo].[update_rows] @row_num=" +"'"+$element+"'"+","+ "@status = 'Fail'"
    $myprocedure +=  $myobj
    $myobj = $null
}
Out-file -filepath $path -inputobject $myprocedure -width 50 -force
```

Or append 3 times to the file:

```
$myArray = @(1,2,3)

$path = "test.txt"

#remove-item $path   if necessary

foreach ($element in $myArray) {
    "EXECUTE [masterdb].[dbo].[update_rows] @row_num=" +"'"+$element+"'"+","+ "@status = 'Fail'" | Out-file -filepath $path -width 50 -force -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks so simple I don't know how I missed it.